# Prolog: Give list to a fact

Tags: prolog

Lets say I'm looking for someones friends.

```
friend(mary, peter).
friend(mary, paul).
friend(mary, john).
friend(mary, justin).

friend(chris, peter).
friend(chris, paul).
friend(chris, conner).
friend(chris, louis).

friend(tyler, justin).
friend(tyler, lindsey).
friend(tyler, frank).
friend(tyler, paul).

friend(dan, justin).
friend(dan, conner).
friend(dan, frank).
friend(dan, peter).
```

In the above example I know that I can do something like

```
friend(X, paul).
```

which will tell me everyone paul is friends with

or also

```
findall(X, friend(X, paul), L).
```

which will return a list of everyone paul is friends with.

Let's say that I want to go a little bit deeper in my search and refine it. So let's say that I was to do

```
findall(X, friend(X, paul), A).
```

To get A to be a list of [mary, chris, tyler]. But then I wanted to further refine that search. I want to be able to put the list into the function (I know this isnt valid but this is my thought pattern for what I want to do) for something like

```
findall(A, friend(A, peter), B).
```

To get back just [mary, chris] this time. And then even FURTHER refine it to say

```
findall(B, friend(B, conner), C).
```

To finally conclude my search to find [chris]

Is this possible? Is there a better or even possible way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Chain conditions

Given I understood it correctly, you want to generate a list of people that are friends with `paul`, `peter` and `connor`. We can do that by "constructing" a goal that aims to satisfy the three conditions:

```
findall(F, (friend(F, paul), friend(F, peter), friend(F, conner)), L).
```

or another conjunction of conditions. These then give:

```
?- findall(F, (friend(F, paul)), L).
L = [mary, chris, tyler].

?- findall(F, (friend(F, paul), friend(F, peter)), L).
L = [mary, chris].

?- findall(F, (friend(F, paul), friend(F, peter), friend(F, conner)), L).
L = [chris].
```

## Filter an existing list with `member/2` in the goal

Or we can also use two calls, and use `member/2` to "emulate" an intersection like:

```
findall(F, friend(F, paul), L1),
findall(F, (member(F, L1), friend(F, peter)), L2).
```

here we thus use `member/2` such that `F2` only takes values from `L1` (the result of the initial `findall/3`), but I think the first way is cleaner and more self explaining: we want after all a list of `F`s that are friends with `paul`, and `peter`, and `conner`.

## Using `maplist/2` to obtain people that are friends with everybody in a list

We can also find the people that are friends with a list of people by using `maplist/2` here:

```
findall(F, maplist(friend(F), [paul, peter, conner]), L).
```

## Post-process with an intersection

We can also make two separate `findall/3` calls, and then calculate the intersection:

```
findall(F, friend(F, paul), L1),
findall(F, friend(F, paul), L2),
intersection(L1, L2, M).
```

Here `M` will thus contain the elements that are both in `L1` and `L2`. But a potential problem here is that the second predicate can generate a lot of results that were not possible with given we filtered with the values of the first predicate.

Comment: we're kind of on the right track. except I want a user to be able to say "refine the search by adding another friend" to narrow down the final person or person's I'm looking for. So I'm trying to recursively call a function that keeps adding a friend to the list. Like the first time they would say paul. Then get a list back and refine that search by saying peter. Then the third time around refine it by calling conner or if they'd like just stop at the first 2 names and be happy with the list of [mary, chris]. My solution was to keep pushing L to say only search from this specific list.

Comment: @Justin: well that is the second strategy: here we thus use `member/2` over the first list (`L1`) to filter that one further. But note that you do not need to call the `findall/3`s immediately after another, the second findall is a "refiner".

Comment: @Justin: furthermore if you want to process a list of persons, then the third approach is likely the most elegant.

Comment: The limit to that is you have to redefine the query every time you want to add a new name to search for. If I could just push the list L to the fact in some way to say findall(L, (friend(L, paul), M). where L is the list generated the first go around and M is the new list, I could recursively call this over and over with one line of code. Does that make sense what I'm trying to accomplish? Then all I have to change is paul, which could really just be from a variable X.

Comment: @Justin: but here you do that with one line of code, you write `findall(F, (member(F, L), friend(F, peter)), M). You only extend the "goal" a bit with `member/2`, but that does not really "restricts" the freedom to alter all kinds of goals.

Comment: So what I'm trying to do is something like find_friend(Y) :-
 write("Add a friend to search for: "),
 read(X),
 findall(Y, friend(Y, X), L), write(L),
 find_friend(L).  This way I'm passing the list recursively and if the user was done with their search they would just escape or I could send it to a different rule.

Comment: `find_friend(Y) :- write("Add a friend to search for: "), read(X), findall(F, (member(F, Y), friend(F, X)), L), find_friend(L). ` and start with `find_friend([_])`.

Comment: PERFECT! The wildcard and the member function fixed everything! Thanks a lot for all your help!